# Comparison of Pandas lookup times

Tags: python, performance, pandas

After experimenting with timing various types of lookups on a Pandas (0.17.1) DataFrame I am left with a few questions.

Here is the set up...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

letters = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z'))]
letter_combinations = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations(letters, 3)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'value': np.random.normal(size=(1000000)), 
        'letter': np.random.choice(letter_combinations, 1000000)
    })
df2 = df1.sort_values('letter')
df3 = df1.set_index('letter')
df4 = df3.sort_index()
```

So df1 looks something like this...

```
print(df1.head(5))


>>>
  letter     value
0    bdh  0.253778
1    cem -1.915726
2    mru -0.434007
3    lnw -1.286693
4    fjv  0.245523
```

Here is the code to test differences in lookup performance...

```
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NON-INDEXED LOOKUPS / UNSORTED DATASET~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
%timeit df1[df1.letter == 'ben']
%timeit df1[df1.letter == 'amy']
%timeit df1[df1.letter == 'abe']

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NON-INDEXED LOOKUPS / SORTED DATASET~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
%timeit df2[df2.letter == 'ben']
%timeit df2[df2.letter == 'amy']
%timeit df2[df2.letter == 'abe']

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~INDEXED LOOKUPS~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
%timeit df3.loc['ben']
%timeit df3.loc['amy']
%timeit df3.loc['abe']

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~SORTED INDEXED LOOKUPS~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
%timeit df4.loc['ben']
%timeit df4.loc['amy']
%timeit df4.loc['abe']
```

And the results...

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NON-INDEXED LOOKUPS / UNSORTED DATASET~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10 loops, best of 3: 59.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 59.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 59.7 ms per loop
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NON-INDEXED LOOKUPS / SORTED DATASET~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 193 ms per loop
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~INDEXED LOOKUPS~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The slowest run took 4.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 41 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 ms per loop
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~SORTED INDEXED LOOKUPS~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The slowest run took 1621.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 242 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop
```

Questions...

1. It's pretty clear why the lookup on the sorted index is so much faster, binary search to get O(log(n)) performance vs O(n) for a full array scan. But, why is the lookup on the sorted non-indexed `df2` column *SLOWER* than the lookup on the unsorted non-indexed column `df1`?
2. What is up with the `The slowest run took x times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached`. Surely, the results aren't being cached. Is it because the created index is lazy and isn't *actually* reindexed until needed? That would explain why it is only on the first call to `.loc[]`.
3. Why isn't an index sorted by default? The fixed cost of the sort can be too much?

Comment: `3. Why isn't an index sorted by default?` - imagine that you've set a custom index and it got sorted, not asking you ...

Comment: 1. - the memory footprint of `df2` is approx. 50% larger compared to `df1`

Comment: @MaxU The reason I ask is because other tools (DBs and R's data.table) sorts by the index by default

Comment: But they don't give you a possibility to have a custom index (unindexed, with duplicates, etc.)

Comment: Why is the memory footprint larger? all(df1.memory_useage() == df2.memory_useage()) is Truthy

Comment: try to execute: `df1.info()` and `df2.info()`... And `df1.memory_usage()['Index'] == df2.memory_usage()['Index']` gives me `False`

Comment: http://imgur.com/zLBtS9M

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. 'Index' isn't a column in df1 or df2.

Comment: it's an index value in the series returned by the `memory_usage()` method. At least in pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Maybe we are using different versions of Pandas? http://imgur.com/Kh0AtZG

Comment: what is you pandas version? `pd.__version__`

Comment: OK, That must be it... 0.17.1. Thanks.

Comment: Please always state the pandas version in questions and answers, otherwise it's not apples-to-apples comparison. Given this was May 2018, are we to assume most answers were [0.18.1 or 0.17.1?](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases?after=v0.20.0rc2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The disparity in these %timeit results

```
In [273]: %timeit df1[df1['letter'] == 'ben']
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop

In [274]: %timeit df2[df2['letter'] == 'ben']
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
```

also shows up in the *pure NumPy* equality comparisons:

```
In [275]: %timeit df1['letter'].values == 'ben'
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop

In [276]: %timeit df2['letter'].values == 'ben'
10 loops, best of 3: 96.5 ms per loop
```

Under the hood, Pandas' `df1['letter'] == 'ben'` [calls a Cython
function](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/lib.pyx#L786)
which loops through the values of the underlying NumPy array,
`df1['letter'].values`. It is essentially doing the same thing as
`df1['letter'].values == 'ben'` but with different handling of NaNs.

Moreover, notice that simply accessing the items in `df1['letter']` in
sequential order can be done more quickly than doing the same for `df2['letter']`:

```
In [11]: %timeit [item for item in df1['letter']]
10 loops, best of 3: 49.4 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit [item for item in df2['letter']]
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop
```

The difference in times within each of these three sets of `%timeit` tests are
roughly the same. I think that is because they all share the same cause.

Since the `letter` column holds strings, the NumPy arrays `df1['letter'].values` and
`df2['letter'].values` have dtype `object` and therefore they hold
pointers to the memory location of the arbitrary Python objects (in this case strings).

Consider the memory location of the strings stored in the DataFrames, `df1` and
`df2`. In CPython the `id` returns the memory location of the object:

```
memloc = pd.DataFrame({'df1': list(map(id, df1['letter'])),
                       'df2': list(map(id, df2['letter'])), })

               df1              df2
0  140226328244040  140226299303840
1  140226328243088  140226308389048
2  140226328243872  140226317328936
3  140226328243760  140226230086600
4  140226328243368  140226285885624
```

The strings in `df1` (after the first dozen or so) tend to appear sequentially
in memory, while sorting causes the strings in `df2` (taken in order) to be
scattered in memory:

```
In [272]: diffs = memloc.diff(); diffs.head(30)
Out[272]: 
         df1         df2
0        NaN         NaN
1     -952.0   9085208.0
2      784.0   8939888.0
3     -112.0 -87242336.0
4     -392.0  55799024.0
5     -392.0   5436736.0
6      952.0  22687184.0
7       56.0 -26436984.0
8     -448.0  24264592.0
9      -56.0  -4092072.0
10    -168.0 -10421232.0
11 -363584.0   5512088.0
12      56.0 -17433416.0
13      56.0  40042552.0
14      56.0 -18859440.0
15      56.0 -76535224.0
16      56.0  94092360.0
17      56.0  -4189368.0
18      56.0     73840.0
19      56.0  -5807616.0
20      56.0  -9211680.0
21      56.0  20571736.0
22      56.0 -27142288.0
23      56.0   5615112.0
24      56.0  -5616568.0
25      56.0   5743152.0
26      56.0 -73057432.0
27      56.0  -4988200.0
28      56.0  85630584.0
29      56.0  -4706136.0
```

Most of the strings in `df1` are 56 bytes apart:

```
In [14]: 
In [16]: diffs['df1'].value_counts()
Out[16]: 
 56.0           986109
 120.0           13671
-524168.0          215
-56.0                1
-12664712.0          1
 41136.0             1
-231731080.0         1
Name: df1, dtype: int64

In [20]: len(diffs['df1'].value_counts())
Out[20]: 7
```

In contrast the strings in `df2` are scattered all over the place:

```
In [17]: diffs['df2'].value_counts().head()
Out[17]: 
-56.0     46
 56.0     44
 168.0    39
-112.0    37
-392.0    35
Name: df2, dtype: int64

In [19]: len(diffs['df2'].value_counts())
Out[19]: 837764
```

When these objects (strings) are located sequentially in memory, their values
can be retrieved more quickly. This is why the equality comparisons performed by
`df1['letter'].values == 'ben'` can be done faster than those in `df2['letter'].values
== 'ben'`. *The lookup time is smaller*.

This memory accessing issue also explains why there is no disparity in the
`%timeit` results for the `value` column.

```
In [5]: %timeit df1[df1['value'] == 0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df2[df2['value'] == 0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 ms per loop
```

`df1['value']` and `df2['value']` are NumPy arrays of dtype `float64`. Unlike object
arrays, their values are packed together contiguously in memory. Sorting `df1`
with `df2 = df1.sort_values('letter')` causes the values in `df2['value']` to be
reordered, but since the values are *copied* into a new NumPy array, the values
are located sequentially in memory. So accessing the values in `df2['value']` can
be done just as quickly as those in `df1['value']`.

Answer (score 5):

(1)  `pandas` currently has no knowledge of the sortedness of a column.
If you want to take advantage of sorted data, you could use `df2.letter.searchsorted`  See @unutbu's answer for an explanation of what's actually causing the difference in time here.

(2)  The hash table that sits underneath the index is lazily created, then cached.

Comment: I don't quite see how the Index type is responsible for the time difference here. OP is using 0.17.1 which doesn't feature `RangeIndex` (both indexes will be of integer type) and new indexes have to be created in both cases. Boolean indexing just boils down to a `take` from the underlying arrays and index type doesn't seem to matter here.

Comment: You're right - I thought the index creation time might have been the issue, but it's not.