# How to change dataframe cells values with "coordinate-like" indexes stored in two lists/vectors/series?

Tags: python, pandas

Apologize if this has been asked before, somehow I am not able to find the answer to this.

Let's say I have two lists of values:

```
rows = [0,1,2]
cols = [0,2,3]
```

that represents indexes of rows and columns respectively. The two lists combined signified sort of coordinates in the matrix, i.e (0,0), (1,2), (2,3).

I would like to use those coordinates to change specific cells of the `dataframe` without using a loop.

In numpy, this is trivial:

```
data = np.ones((4,4))
data[rows, cols] = np.nan

array([[nan,  1.,  1.,  1.],
      [ 1.,  1., nan,  1.],
      [ 1.,  1.,  1., nan],
      [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

But in pandas, it seems I am stuck with a loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((4,4)))
for _r, _c in zip(rows, cols): 
    df.iat[_r, _c] = np.nan
```

**Is there a way to use to vectors that lists coordinate-like index to directly modify cells in pandas?**

---

Please note that **the answer is not to use iloc instead**, this selects the intersection of entire rows and columns.

Comment: Ummm, seems like you are using the right way, I am not sure whether we have alternative solution for this question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple! Exploit the fact that pandas is built on top of `numpy` and use `DataFrame.values`

```
df.values[rows, cols] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: this is `numpy` as well buddy .

Comment: well pandas is on itself numpy no?

Comment: thanks a lot, I promised I tried this, but somehow I made a mess with the indexes and ended doing it wrong, now it works!!. My real case is obviously more convoluted and endend doing something that I realize now is silly like this `models.loc[someselector,:].values[range(_idxmin.shape[0]), _idxmin] = np.nan`, it was a matter of rethinking my indexes.

Comment: @Yuca, pandas uses numpy in the background, but in the last couple of days I am learning (the hard way) that there are important differences when you are trying to create very efficient code, even for things that look [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932428/obtain-min-and-idxmin-or-max-and-idxmax-at-the-same-time-simultaneou/51932429#51932429).

Comment: @toto_tico thank you for sharing your experience, I agree, the devil is in the details!