# Does sorting reduce computational cost while working with huge datasets in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I work with huge datasets in python and mostly I use Pandas to work with datasets and perform data analyses. So, even simple and straight-forward queries take significant time. I was wondering if sorting datasets and saving them for further analyses could significantly reduce computational cost while getting queries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison of Pandas lookup times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254067/comparison-of-pandas-lookup-times)